# Find the value of $\sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac 1 {5^{n+1}-5^n+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac 1 {5^{n+1}-5^n+1}$$

I can factorize denominator to $4\times5^n+1$ to confirm the series does not diverge,
But how do I calculate its actual sum?

The series is not a telescoping series nor I can partial factorise.
I get confused due to $+1$  in the denominator.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can have a very good (and simple) upper bound using the fact that $4\times5^n+1>4\times5^n$

Comment: If I can approximate the sum it would be lot easier. But what about its actual value?

Comment: The sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-a^k}$ can be expressed in terms of the Q-Polygamma function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html 

Just rewrite $5^{n+1}-5^n=4\times 5^n$ and massage the sum a bit, perhaps?

Comment: This gives a quite good approximation. The exact value looks diificult (at least to me).

Comment: You probably don't really care about it's decimal expansion, but here it is: $0.0600158790999132877445961652233...$

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo. You are totally right, for sure. The problem is (translated from French) :*isn't it a big hammer for a small fly ?*

Comment: Probably the fly is too strong to kill with a simple swatter. We'll need quite a large hammer for this

Comment: I see so there is no easy way to find its actual value - at least within the scope of this module syllabus, Thanks a lot you kind people.

Comment: @Claude nice one. But if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-a^k}$ (surely a small fly) were expressible in a simpler form, wouldn't the Wolfram hammers mention it ;-) ?

Comment: Even wolfram does not give an exact value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series doesn't have a closed form (except for a very complicated one involving Q-Polygamma function, as was said in a comment), however, we can transform it to get much better convergence.

$$\frac{1}{4 \cdot 5^n+1}=\frac{1}{4 \cdot 5^n} \left(1-\frac{1}{4 \cdot 5^n}+\frac{1}{4^2 \cdot 5^{2n}}-\frac{1}{4^3 \cdot 5^{3n}}+\cdots \right)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^k \cdot 5^{k n}}=\frac{1}{4^k} \left( \dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{5^{k}}}-1 \right)=\frac{1}{4^k (5^k-1)}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4 \cdot 5^n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{4^k (5^k-1)}=0.06001587909991328$$

Why is this series better? Since it is alternating, it provides upper and lower bounds, unlike the first series, which converges monotonely from below.

It also just gives much better approximations, both in terms of their numerical value and the size of their denominators.

Let's denote:

$$A_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{4 \cdot 5^n+1}$$

$$B_N=\sum_{k=1}^{N} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{4^k (5^k-1)}$$

Now compare:

---

$$A_2=\frac{122}{2121}=0.0575200$$

$$A_3=\frac{7027}{118069}=0.0595161$$

---

$$B_2=\frac{23}{384}=0.0598958$$

$$B_3=\frac{1429}{23808}=0.0600218$$

---

$$0.0598958<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4 \cdot 5^n+1}<0.0600218$$

---

Here is the plot of both $A_N$ and $B_N$ up to $N=10$

[image]